# ibus does not work on chrome

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, ibus

I am using Xubuntu 22.04 and using ibus-cangjie.

It works just fine on every X app except for chrome, and it seems only inside applications such as google chat or slack.  In chrome apps, often cangjie keys seem to disappear, and there is this error message:

(google-chrome:1257322): Gdk-WARNING **: **hh:mm:ss.sss**: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel

So if I type a period, I can often proceed to continue typing, but it is very very annoying.

Comment: You might want to see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437764

Comment: Dear Terrance: thanks for pointing this one, I already tried this one and it didn't work.

Comment: One thing that can really help us help you is if you add as much detail of things you have tried so that we're not guessing.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Terrance, so I am using

ibus 1.5.26, engine: cangjie,  Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124 
GNU Emacs 27.1 (works, but after I restart ibus, I need to restart Emacs for Chinese
Telegram desktop 4.4.1 (does not work if I use the answer Terrance first suggested).
Signal desktop 6.0.1, Mozilla Firefox 108.0.1 (these works well)
Running under Xorg 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5

From time to time my cangjie input is swallowed in an chrome app, such as in the input box for google chat.